# Is the progression between night and day time based or event based in Risen?

Tags: risen

I haven't been playing for very long and I know it was daylight at one point, now I feel like night is taking forever! I can't tell if the sun cycle happened because I moved around or if it is just on a clock cycle. If it's time based, how long does it take? If it's event based, which areas trigger the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the progression between day and night is time based, so 5 Minutes in realtime match 1 hour Ingame-Risen Time.

But i think that your day-night cycle is corrupt! Its a well known Bug taking place on AMD Dual Core PCs.
A Solution is to get the latest AMD Dual Core Optimizer.
Hope that works for you: [AMD Optimizer](http://support.amd.com/de/Search/results.aspx?k=dual%20core%20optimizer)

Comment: hmm, I have an i7 but thanks for pointing that out, others may find it useful

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, the risen day-night cycle is based on time.

There are a few options to fast-forward time (and one to slow it down) though:

1. You can sleep. During the game you will get a few places "of your own", but there are also plenty of beds in the wild etc. you can sleep in without trouble. This will allow you to fast-forward to the following morning, noon, evening, or midnight (in addition to fully healing you).
2. Using the console, there are a few commands to control time. To activate the console, type "minsky" quickly. A message will appear if you got it right. You can now access the console by using the key left of "1" and above tab.

   1. The console command `time HH.MM` will set the time to HH:MM.
   2. `timescale X` changes the relationship between RL time to in-game/Risen time. One source says the default time scale is 1, but I haven't found a way to show default values in the console.

Note that I haven't actually played around with the console that much, and I haven't experimented with `time` or `timescale`. Using `help` in the console will give you some guidance, and likewise will the tab-completion help you enter the right commands.

See also the "Time" entry in the Risen Wikia's FAQ: http://risen.wikia.com/wiki/Risen_FAQ#Time